# Kotlin File Reading, use block not catching all exceptions

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm doing some file IO with Kotlin and wanted to use those great extension methods provided in the library

```
  val cacheDir = externalCacheDir
            File(cacheDir, "missingfile.dat")
                    .inputStream()
                    .use {
                       //Use the file in someway
                    }
```

So this works great when the file is present
but if the file is missing, I get a `FileNotFoundException`.

This is expected. But If I want to correctly handle it I end up breaking that awesome Kotlin syntax by wrapping it in another try catch

So I dug into the code a bit and looked at the `inputStream()` call

I see this

```
public inline fun File.inputStream(): FileInputStream {
    return FileInputStream(this)
}
```

So I thought I'd make my own extension function that does this. Wraps in a try catch so at least its not visible when using it

```
fun File.inputStreamOrNull(): FileInputStream? {
    return try {
        FileInputStream(this)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }
}
```

However, a null pointer exception is thrown within the `use` block

```
 val cacheDir = externalCacheDir
            File(cacheDir, "protsfasfasfaso.mams")
                    .inputStreamOrNull()
                    .use {
                      //Going to use null input stream :O 
                    }
```

However, the `use` block does not actually catch this even though the high order function is wrapped in a try catch too which ends up crashing the app

```
public inline fun <T : Closeable?, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R {
    var closed = false
    try {
        return block(this)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        closed = true
        try {
            this?.close()
        } catch (closeException: Exception) {
        }
        throw e
    } finally {
        if (!closed) {
            this?.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone got any ideas about this one?
I know the quick fix but is there a way around to keep that cool Kotlin style?
Thanks for reading

Comment: You should not get NPE inside `use` lambda in the last example, unless you specifically asked for it with `!!` operator.

Comment: @Ilya I did not use !! so it is strange the exception is uncaught even though it is wrapped in a try catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `.use { ... }` call into a null-safe call (`?.`), then it will return the return value of `use` or `null`.